# How to compare a variable to first part of HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: php, http, url, if-statement, uri

Please tell me, if I got a variable `$var` which returns: `http://foo.com` - then how can I check whether this uri is identical to what `$referrer` returns (given there is one), or to it's first part if `$referrer = http://foo.com/oof/` or longer..?

With (any better way?):

```
$referrer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

Basically I'd like to have an if/else case, for when the uri matches and when it doesn't.
I'm also wondering how to it make hack-safe if you will, so that it can't be cheated when `$referrer` is fake like such: `http://badsite.com/file.php?param1=http://foo.com`, and so that here the `http://foo.com` part won't be considered a legit match.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the domain only:

```
$yoursite = ""; //Your site url without http:// or www.
$yoursite2 = ""; //Type your domain with www. this time

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$domain = parse_url($referer); 

if($domain['host'] == $yoursite || $domain['host'] == $yoursite2) {
     //Run your code here normally
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Please tell me though, does the `'host'` part mean that only the initial instance of `http://....com` in `$domain` would be checked to match, hence won't be susceptible to cheating like I mentioned in the original question?

Comment: You can't be 100% sure about the referrer because someone can interrupt the http request and alter the referrer and you wouldn't know.

Comment: Maybe you should start a session and store the referrer in it. It is the only variables that the user can't reach or know content.

Comment: This is really good idea. But how can referrer same as domain?

Comment: @DenizPorsuk except the first time the user opens up your site, he would be navigating from one page to another on your domain. So if you want to protect a page from direct access or hot linking just don't make it your home page.

Answer (score 2):

Quite literally:

```
if( substr($referrer, 0, strlen($var)) == $var)
```

"If the substring from the start of the referrer of the same length as the search term, is equal to the search term..."

In some cases, referrers may not be sent in the lowercase you might expect. To allow for this case, consider trying:

```
if( strcasecmp( substr($referrer, 0, strlen($var)), $var) == 0)
```

This performs a case-insensitive comparison on the start of the referrer vs. the search term.

Comment: Thanks! But please tell me - does this check only the length and not the content of the string itself? Anyhow, I'd like it to match the `$var` content to a the correct part of `$referrer` even if the latter is longer, though with regard to bogus uri filtering...

Comment: I have read it, I think what I asked for are reasonable clarifications as you only mention string length. Please kindly give me an answer in that regard, or in short, please just tell me whether or not the code you gave me answers all of the concerns as mentioned in my question. I'd really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: I gave a literal explanation. Pay attention: "If the substring [...] of the referrer [...] is equal to the search term"

Comment: With all due respect, can't you just say yes or no as to whether your code does all I mentioned in the question? - Then your much appreciated (no sarcasm!), free of charge help will be utilized by me to it's full potential. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry if I came off as rude or condescending here, but in all honesty a person with as high as reputation score as myself would not put said reputation at risk by posting incomplete answers, at least not without proper disclaimer. Since I posted no such disclaimer, you may assume that the answer I have given is intended to be a complete answer to your question. Please try it, and if it doesn't work or you can find some way to break it, then let me know and I will correct it as needed.

Comment: You aren't rude, and I did get your solution to work. As to the reputation thing, I see... And thanks again.

Comment: I use it to verify that the referrer starts with http or https as the referrer can be altered, so I only accept valid referrer. Thank you!